# aspx file upload control with drop down list path

Tags: asp.net, upload, drop-down-menu, devexpress

I have an aspx upload control and a asp drop down list with folders as the items

I am trying to get the file to upload to the directory/ the selected folder ( from the drop down )

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            string uploadDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
            //string uploadDirectory = "//DOCSD9F1/TECHDOCS/";

            string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

            string uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(uploadDirectory + uploadFolder + "/" + fileName);
            e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using MapPath just before saving file?

```
e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(uploadDirectory + uploadFolder + "/" + fileName));
```